latex threeparttable issues

I am using \threeparttable to create a table in latex. The problem is with this command the caption of the table is automatically splitting into half or random width and not in a full sentence width. Is there any way to fix it?
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[hbtp]
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llcc}
\toprule
Surface Condition & pH & $\Gamma_{\rm e}^{a}$ & $\Gamma_{\rm e}- \Gamma_{\rm e}^{\rm SPM}$ \\
\midrule
SPM w/o FeCl3$^*$ & 3 & 1.7 & 15.2 \\
SPM FeCl3 & 2 & 5.6 & 11.3 \\
SPM FeCl3 & 3 & 3.0 & 17.9 \\
SPM FeCl3 & 4 & 16.6 & 3.0 \\
SPM FeCl3 & 5 & 3.0 & 10.7 \\
SPM FeCl3 & 7 & 16.5 & 14.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Summary of $\Gamma_{\rm e}$ calculated from ED profiles extracted from XRR data.} 
\label{table:ref_gamma}
\begin{tablenotes}
    \footnotesize
    \item [a] The excess of surface electron density in ED profiles, $\Gamma_{\rm e}=\int[\rho(z)-\rho_{\rm sub}(z)]{\rm d}z$. \\
    \item[*] $\Gamma_{\rm e}$ for SPM w/o \ch{FeCl3} is considered as $\Gamma_{\rm e}^{\rm SPM}$ and used to calculate ions ED. 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}
\end{document}


If you cross-post the same question on multiple sites, you should include links to all other versions of the question in every post, even in the original one. X-posting without explicit links has the risk of wasting both the time of users who might put time and effort into answering a post, which already has an answer elsewhere, as well as the time of users who might have the same problem but can't find the solutions you might have gotten on one of the other sites you x-posted your question

x-post https://stackoverflow.com/q/78992585/2777074

Adding a MWE including a class would be much more useful than posting the same question yet again.

Welcome to TeX.SX! I cannot reproduce the problem with the shown code. Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

welcome! off-topic: you should not use two-character font switches in latex e.g. \rm. use \textrm, \rmfamily, \mathrm etc. instead. related but still off-topic: threeparttable expects the caption to be the first thing specified, so it should be before the tabular.


The problem [with threeparttable is that] the caption of the table is automatically splitting into half or random width and not in a full sentence width. Is there any way to fix it?

What you disdainfully (or is it derisively?) call a "half or random width" is actually the width of the tabular environment that's associated with the caption in question (and the tablenotes environment as well).

The threeparttable environment has three formal components: (a) a caption, (b) a tabular-like environment, and (c) a tablenotes environment.

The threepartable environment has two main purposes: (a) the \tnote macro and \tablenotes environment, which let users create fairly free-format footnotes; and (b) to assure that the widths of the caption and tablenotes environment don't exceed the width of the associated tabular environment.
If you have no use for these two purposes, don't use the threeparttable machinery.


Incidentally, what's your reason for failing to use \tnote directives? I.e., why do you write $\Gamma_{\rm e}^{a}$ and SPM w/o FeCl3$^*$ instead of $\Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}$\tnote{a} and SPM w/o \ch{FeCl3}\tnote{*}? If you're going to employ the threeparttable environment, you might as well use its tools, no?
Do look closely at the following screenshot. Do you notice that the widths of the table, the caption, and the tablenotes are all the same? That's not by accident or happenstance, but by purposeful design.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{chemformula,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[hbtp]
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering

\begin{tabular}{@{}lccc@{}}
\toprule
Surface Condition & pH & $\Gamma_{\!\mathrm{e}}\tnote{a}$ & $\Gamma_{\!\mathrm{e}}-\Gamma_{\!\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{SPM}}$ \\
\midrule
SPM w/o \ch{FeCl3}\tnote{*} & 3 & 1.7 & 15.2 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3} & 2 & 5.6 & 11.3 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3} & 3 & 3.0 & 17.9 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3} & 4 & 16.6 & 3.0 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3} & 5 & 3.0 & 10.7 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3} & 7 & 16.5 & 14.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\caption{Summary of $\Gamma_{\!\mathrm{e}}$ calculated from ED profiles extracted from XRR data.} 
\label{table:ref_gamma}

\smallskip
\begin{tablenotes}
    \footnotesize
    \item[a] The excess of surface electron density in ED profiles, $\Gamma_{\!\mathrm{e}}=\int[\rho(z)-\rho_{\mathrm{sub}}(z)]\,\mathrm{d}z$. \\
    \item[*] $\Gamma_{\!\mathrm{e}}$ for SPM w/o \ch{FeCl3} is considered as $\Gamma_{\!\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{SPM}}$ and used to calculate ions ED. 
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
\end{document}


Copied your code exactly as it is. But my result is the same

@Binay - Same as what?

The caption is split into half of the page, which is the issue I had before.  Below are the packages I have. Just a reference in case any of them cause any issues.
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{lineno}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\newcommand\numberthis{\addtocounter{equation}{1}\tag{\theequation}}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}

Alright. I figured it out. if you put the caption right before the start of \threeparttable it works.

Sure, you can remove the \caption statement entirely from the threeparttable environment.

It seems you don't want threeparttable.
Here I measure the width of the table, so the notes can be typeset below it with the same width.
Please, note that commands such as \rm have been deprecated for about 30 years. Also the superscript for the note in the table header should be outside the formula.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,enumitem}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\newsavebox{\tablebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[hbtp]
\centering

\begin{lrbox}{\tablebox}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{2}{S[table-format=2.1]} @{}}
\toprule
Surface Condition & pH &
  {$\Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}$}\textsuperscript{a} &
  {$\Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}- \Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{SPM}}$} \\
\midrule
SPM w/o \ch{FeCl3}$^*$ & 3 &  1.7 & 15.2 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3}         & 2 &  5.6 & 11.3 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3}         & 3 &  3.0 & 17.9 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3}         & 4 & 16.6 &  3.0 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3}         & 5 &  3.0 & 10.7 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3}         & 7 & 16.5 & 14.0 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular}
\end{lrbox}

\usebox{\tablebox}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\wd\tablebox}
\footnotesize
\begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=*]
  \item[a] The excess of surface electron density in ED profiles, 
           $\Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}=\int[\rho(z)-\rho_{\mathrm{sub}}(z)]\,\mathrm{d}z$.
  \item[*] $\Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}$ for SPM w/o \ch{FeCl3} is considered as 
           $\Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{SPM}}$ and used to calculate ions ED. 
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\caption{Summary of $\Gamma_{\rm e}$ calculated from ED profiles extracted from XRR data.} 
\label{table:ref_gamma}

\end{table*}

\end{document}


If you want the caption above the table, load also \usepackage{caption}.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,enumitem,caption}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\newsavebox{\tablebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[hbtp]
\centering

\caption{Summary of $\Gamma_{\rm e}$ calculated from ED profiles extracted from XRR data.} 
\label{table:ref_gamma}

\begin{lrbox}{\tablebox}
\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{2}{S[table-format=2.1]} @{}}
\toprule
Surface Condition & pH &
  {$\Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}$}\textsuperscript{a} &
  {$\Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}- \Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{SPM}}$} \\
\midrule
SPM w/o \ch{FeCl3}$^*$ & 3 &  1.7 & 15.2 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3}         & 2 &  5.6 & 11.3 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3}         & 3 &  3.0 & 17.9 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3}         & 4 & 16.6 &  3.0 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3}         & 5 &  3.0 & 10.7 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3}         & 7 & 16.5 & 14.0 \\
\midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
\end{tabular}
\end{lrbox}

\usebox{\tablebox}
\begin{minipage}[t]{\wd\tablebox}
\footnotesize
\begin{itemize}[nosep,leftmargin=*]
  \item[a] The excess of surface electron density in ED profiles, 
           $\Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}=\int[\rho(z)-\rho_{\mathrm{sub}}(z)]\,\mathrm{d}z$.
  \item[*] $\Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}$ for SPM w/o \ch{FeCl3} is considered as 
           $\Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{SPM}}$ and used to calculate ions ED. 
\end{itemize}
\end{minipage}

\end{table*}

\end{document}


You may also use threeparttable, but the output of the notes is really suboptimal.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx,enumitem,caption}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\newsavebox{\tablebox}

\begin{document}

\begin{table*}[hbtp]
\centering

\caption{Summary of $\Gamma_{\rm e}$ calculated from ED profiles extracted from XRR data.} 
\label{table:ref_gamma}

\begin{threeparttable}

\begin{tabular}{@{} ll *{2}{S[table-format=2.1]} @{}}
\toprule
Surface Condition & pH &
  {$\Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}$}\textsuperscript{a} &
  {$\Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}- \Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{SPM}}$} \\
\midrule
SPM w/o \ch{FeCl3}$^*$ & 3 &  1.7 & 15.2 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3}         & 2 &  5.6 & 11.3 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3}         & 3 &  3.0 & 17.9 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3}         & 4 & 16.6 &  3.0 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3}         & 5 &  3.0 & 10.7 \\
SPM \ch{FeCl3}         & 7 & 16.5 & 14.0 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\footnotesize
  \item[a] The excess of surface electron density in ED profiles, 
           $\Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}=\int[\rho(z)-\rho_{\mathrm{sub}}(z)]\,\mathrm{d}z$.
  \item[*] $\Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}$ for SPM w/o \ch{FeCl3} is considered as 
           $\Gamma_{\mathrm{e}}^{\mathrm{SPM}}$ and used to calculate ions ED. 
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}

\end{table*}

\end{document}



I figured it out. if you put the caption right before the start of \threeparttable, it works. See the Figure.

Package threeparttable, as names suggest, has three parts: caption which width is the same as table width, table body and table notes. Apparently, you not like to exploit features of the first table part -- limit caption width to width of table, so you simply move caption and label to immediately after \begin{table} (what you do in your answer).
Here is some off-topic suggestion: if you willing to use talltblr of tabularray package and siunitx package for formatting numbers in the last two table's columns, that the you may consider the following MWE (Minimal Working Example):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
   \begin{table}[hbtp]
   \newcommand\e{\mathrm{e}}% for global use, move this line to preamble
\caption{Summary of $\Gamma_{\!\e}$ calculated from ED profiles extracted from XRR data.} 
\label{table:ref_gamma}
    \centering
    \DefTblrTemplate{note-text}{default}{\InsertTblrNoteText\medskip}% for global change, move this line to preamble
\begin{talltblr}[
    entry=none,     % <---
    label=none,     % <---
note{a} = {The excess of surface electron density in ED profiles, $\Gamma_{\!\e}=\int[\rho(z)-\rho_{\mathrm{sub}}(z)]\,\mathrm{d}z$.
           },
note{*} = {$\Gamma_{\!\mathrm{e}}$ for SPM w/o \ce{FeCl3} is considered as $\Gamma_{\!\e}^{\mathrm{SPM}}$ and used to calculate ions ED.}
                ]{colspec = { lc *{2}{Q[c, si={table-format=2.1}]} },
                  row{1} = {guard}
                 }
    \toprule
Surface Condition & pH & $\Gamma_{\!\e}$\TblrNote{a} & $\Gamma_{\!\e} - \Gamma_{\!\e}^{\mathrm{SPM}}$ \\
    \midrule
SPM \ce{FeCl3}                  & 2 &  5.6 & 11.3 \\
SPM \ce{FeCl3}                  & 3 &  3.0 & 17.9 \\
SPM \ce{FeCl3}                  & 4 & 16.6 &  3.0 \\
SPM \ce{FeCl3}                  & 5 &  3.0 & 10.7 \\
SPM \ce{FeCl3}                  & 7 & 16.5 & 14.0 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{talltblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}


